# How to load elasticsearch in python using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, sqlalchemy

Am trying to connect to elasticsearch using below in Jupyter notebook

```
engine = create_engine("elasticsearch+https://user:pwd@host:9200/")
```

however it gives the error:

> Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:elasticsearch.https

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you installed [elasticsearch-dbapi](https://github.com/preset-io/elasticsearch-dbapi/)?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; Simply install elasticsearch-dbapi:

```
pip install elasticsearch-dbapi
```

Details:
SQLAlchemy uses "dialects" to support reading and writing to different DBMS's.

SQLAlchemy natively supports MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres and SQLite as well as others. Here is the full list: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/

**Elastic is not in that list**. Hence, you need to install a library that delivers the dialect for reading/writing from/to Elastic.